# Customising the .NET PrintPreviewDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, print-preview

Currently i'm using the PrintPreviewDialog to open a window to preview the printed pages before they are sent to a printer. The problem is though that it first appears very small, at the top left of the screen and the buttons are too small.

[alt text http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/4577/printpreview.png](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/4577/printpreview.png)

Is there anyway i can set a starting size for this dialog or start position or even make the little buttons a little bigger? Or do i need to implement my own?

Comment: Are you talking about the toolbar buttons? and the document? What is your screen resolution?

Comment: I'm talking about the buttons above in the image. They are standard buttons attached to the PrintPreviewDialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the toolstrip. Been a while since I used a toolstrip. But I would think you could make it work...

```
    Dim cnts As Form.ControlCollection = Me.PrintPreviewDialog1.Controls
    Dim toolstrp As ToolStrip = DirectCast(cnts(1), ToolStrip)
    toolstrp.Height = 50

    Dim tsbtn As ToolStripButton = toolstrp.Items(0)
    tsbtn.AutoSize = False
    tsbtn.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
    tsbtn.Size = New Size(65, 50)

    Me.PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Nice work-around, i guess i could access and mess about with lots of properties like this. In the end though, i've implemented my own print preview dialog.

Answer (score 1):

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/84be8f8b72.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/84be8f8b72.png)

This is my own PrvDialog. You can create a new Form, add to it a new ToolStrip, a PrintPreviewControl and implement your PrintPreviewDialog Funcionality.

This is a simple option. More simple than try to modify original PrintPreviewDialog behavior.

You can see sample at Code-Project. An Enhaced PrintPreviewDialog (CoolPrintPreviewDialog).

Comment: Thanks, i did indeed implement my own which was more simple than trying to work with the built in one.